# What is the Fourier transform of an M like function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, absolute-value

Given the function
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\vert x \vert& \text{, for }\;\vert x\vert\le M \\ 
0 & \text{, otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
for some constant $M$.

What would be the form for the continuous Fourier transform of this function, i.e.
$$
\hat{f}(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\;e^{2\pi i x k}\;dx=?
$$

**Edit:**

I used Wolfram Alpha with the query

```
fourier transform Piecewise[{{abs(x),-M<x<M},{0,x>=M},{0,x<=-M}}]
```

and got the answer is
$$
\mathcal{F}_{x}[f(x)](\omega)=\frac{\left(\theta(-M)-1\right)e^{-iM\omega}\left(-1+e^{iM\omega}\right)\left(iM\omega+e^{iM\omega}\left(-1+iM\omega\right)+1\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}\omega^{2}}
$$
Which after some algebra turns out to be
$$
\mathcal{F}_{x}[f(x)](\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\left(\frac{\cos M\omega+M\omega\sin M\omega-1}{\omega^{2}}\right)
$$

Using the hint I got here (which I actually already knew), and the fact that 
$$
\int x\cos nx\: dx = \frac{x\sin nx}{n}+\frac{\cos nx}{n^{2}}+C
$$
(easily proven using integration by parts and simple change of variables), I get another thing:
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(k) 
&= -\underbrace{\int_{-M}^0 dx \, x \, e^{i 2 \pi k x}}_{x\mapsto -x} + \int_0^M dx \,  x \, e^{i 2 \pi k x}\\ 
&= \int_0^M dx \,x\,  \left ( e^{i 2 \pi k x}+ e^{-i 2 \pi k x} \right ) \\ 
&= 2 \int_0^M dx \,x \,  \cos{2 \pi k x} \\
&= 2 \left(\left[\frac{x\sin\left(2\pi kx\right)}{2\pi k}\right]_{0}^{M}+\left[\frac{\cos\left(2\pi kx\right)}{\left(2\pi k\right)^{2}}\right]_{0}^{M}\right)\\
&= 2\left(\frac{M\sin\left(M2\pi k\right)}{2\pi k}+\frac{\cos\left(M2\pi k\right)}{\left(2\pi k\right)^{2}}-\frac{1}{\left(2\pi k\right)^{2}}\right)
\end{align} 
$$

Did I miss something? Am I doing something wrong? Is Wolfram Alpha wrong?

**Edit:**
If we use the convention
$$
\hat{f}\left(\omega\right)=\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}f\left(x\right)e^{-i\omega x}\, dx
$$
then we get the same result as Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Have you tried plugging that form into the integrand and applying integration by parts, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\begin{align}\hat{f}(k) &= -\underbrace{\int_{-M}^0 dx \, x \, e^{i 2 \pi k x}}_{x\mapsto -x} + \int_0^M dx \,  x \, e^{i 2 \pi k x}\\ &= \int_0^M dx \,x\,  \left ( e^{i 2 \pi k x}+ e^{-i 2 \pi k x} \right ) \\ &= 2 \int_0^M dx \,x \,  \cos{2 \pi k x} \end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Please see my edit. Thanks.

Comment: Well, clearly WA's FT definition is different than yours.  Otherwise, a superficial check looks good.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the continuous Fourier transform is well defined up to some normalisation constant the sign before i. But I see now (wikipedia) there is another convention that works.